# Elevenagram Round H google kickstart

Tags: c++, algorithm, math

I have been trying to understand the solution to the problem elevanagram from kickstart round H 2019.
    https://codingcompetitions.withgoogle.com/kickstart/round/0000000000050edd/00000000001a286d

> **Given a number that consists of digits from 1-9, can you rearrange the digits to create a number that is divisible by 11?**
>
> Since the number might be quite large, you are given integers A1, A2, ..., A9. There are Ai digits i in the number, for all i.
>
> **Input** : The first line of the input gives the number of test cases, T. T lines >follow. Each line contains the nine integers A1, A2, ..., A9.
>
> **Output** : For each test case, output one line containing Case #x: y, where x is the >test case number (starting from 1) and y is YES if the digits can be >rearranged to create a multiple of 11, and NO otherwise.

**Limits**
Time limit: 20 seconds per test set.
Memory limit: 1GB.

> Test set 1 (Visible): 0 ≤ Ai ≤ 20, for all i.
>
> Test set 2 (Hidden) : 0 ≤ Ai ≤ 10^9, for all i.

The analysis of the problem says : Assume the positive number of digits i is Pi, and negative number of digits i is Ai - Pi. Then, we will have the following three equations:

(1) Σ Pi = ceil(sum(A) / 2)

(2) Σ i × (Pi - (Ai - Pi)) % 11 = 0

(3) 0 ≤ Pi ≤ Ai

In order to solve this, initially we can put half the number of each digits to be in positive partition (e.g. Pi = Ai / 2, take care of odd numbers), and then try to adjust each Pi to satisfy equation (2). For each i, we can adjust its Pi from -Ai / 2 to Ai / 2.

We can prove the two following conclusions:

If there are at least two numbers of Ai ≥ 10, then the solution must exist.

This is very easy to prove. We can only adjust these two digits from -5 to 5, and each adjustment will result in a different remain value of modulo 11. Thus, we will get 0 finally.

If there are at least three numbers of Ai ≥ 6, then the solution must exist.

To prove this, we can prove that:

For any 1 ≤ i < j < k ≤ 9, 0 ≤ r ≤ 10, the following equations:

(1) (i * x1 + j * x2 + k * x3) % 11 = r

(2) x1 + x2 + x3 = 0

(3) -3 ≤ xi ≤ 3

will have a valid solution.

Why is it correct that if there are at least 2 numbers with count>=10 or even one number with count >=20, then the solution always exists?Is there a simple math proof for both?
Also, I was going through a submission of the same problem.

```
   #include <iostream>
   #include <algorithm>
   #include <fstream>
   #include <vector>
   #include <deque>
   #include <assert.h>
   #include <queue>
   #include <stack>
   #include <set>
   #include <map>
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <string.h>
   #include <utility>
   #include <math.h>
   #include <bitset>
   #include <iomanip>
   #include <complex>

   using namespace std;

   #define rep(i, a, b) for (int i = (a), i##_end_ = (b); i < i##_end_; ++i)
   #define debug(...) fprintf(stderr, __VA_ARGS__)
   #define mp make_pair
   #define x first
   #define y second
   #define pb push_back
   #define SZ(x) (int((x).size()))
   #define ALL(x) (x).begin(), (x).end()

   template<typename T> inline bool chkmin(T &a, const T &b) { return a > b ? a = b, 1 : 0; }
   template<typename T> inline bool chkmax(T &a, const T &b) { return a < b ? a = b, 1 : 0; }
   template<typename T> inline bool smin(T &a, const T &b)   { return a > b ? a = b : a;    }
   template<typename T> inline bool smax(T &a, const T &b)   { return a < b ? a = b : a;    }

   typedef long long LL;

   const int N = (int) 505, mod = (int) 0;
   int cnt[10], dp[N][11], odp[N][11];
   int main() {
        int tc;
        cin >> tc;
        for (int tt = 1; tt <= tc; ++tt) {
            cout << "Case #" << tt << ": ";
            int sum = 0;
            for (int j = 1; j < 10; ++j) {
                cin >> cnt[j];
                if (cnt[j] > 20) {
                    cnt[j] = 20 + (cnt[j] & 1); 
                }
                sum += cnt[j];
            }
            memset(dp, 0, sizeof dp);
            dp[0][0] = 1;
            for (int j = 1; j < 10; ++j) {
                memcpy(odp, dp, sizeof dp);
                memset(dp, 0, sizeof dp);
                for (int pick = 0; pick <= cnt[j]; ++pick) {
                    for (int lpick = 0; lpick + pick < N; ++lpick) {
                        for (int lmod = 0; lmod < 11; ++lmod) {
                            int nmod = (lmod + pick * j + (11 - j) * (cnt[j] - pick)) % 11;
                            dp[lpick + pick][nmod] |= odp[lpick][lmod];
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            if (dp[sum / 2][0]) {
                cout << "YES\n";
            } else {
                cout << "NO\n";
            }

        }
   }
```

I understand why all the counts have been reduced to at most 20, but why are we looping on the residue class as well? Why are we adding the residue to the actual residue obtained?
Please help.I have been trying to figure out the logic for 2 days but no success.Any help how to go about understanding the problem is appreciated.

Comment: Please include the problem instead of just a link.

Comment: I have included the problem statement as well.

Comment: Is the broken? Are you asking for a fix?

Comment: @nicomp No I am just asking for explanation of certain points. The code is a correct submission by a user if that's what you meant by broken.

Comment: Not sure if this is helpful, but here is my solution in python: https://github.com/goodwordalchemy/google_coding_competitions/blob/master/kickstartH2019/elevanagram.py, which passes both test sets.  I think I've got clearer variable names and abstractions that might make it easier to understand.  Here is an earlier version of it where I used recursion, which might make the thinking process even easier to understand: https://github.com/goodwordalchemy/google_coding_competitions/blob/b2293c057dcc03749548591cd7188a4576c77422/kickstartH2019/elevanagram.py.